# How to prevent auto expand of nz-tree in nz-zorro while drag and drop

Tags: angular

I'm using nz-zerro in my Angular project, where I have used nz-tree.

When I drag a node from tree then the other nodes from the tree auto expand as soon as hover the dragged node on it.

Is it possible to turn this off?

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the 'eventTriggerChanged' function by removing the commented code:

```
this.nzTreeComponent.eventTriggerChanged = function (event: NzFormatEmitEvent): void {
  const node = event.node!;
  switch (event.eventName) {
    case 'expand':
      this.renderTree();
      this.nzExpandChange.emit(event);
      break;
    case 'click':
      this.nzClick.emit(event);
      break;
    case 'dblclick':
      this.nzDblClick.emit(event);
      break;
    case 'contextmenu':
      this.nzContextMenu.emit(event);
      break;
    case 'check':
      this.nzTreeService.setCheckedNodeList(node);
      if (!this.nzCheckStrictly) {
        this.nzTreeService.conduct(node);
      }
      const eventNext = this.nzTreeService.formatEvent('check', node, event.event!);
      this.nzCheckBoxChange.emit(eventNext);
      break;
    case 'dragstart':
      if (node.isExpanded) {
        node.setExpanded(!node.isExpanded);
        this.renderTree();
      }
      this.nzOnDragStart.emit(event);
      break;
    case 'dragenter':
      // Remove this part
      /* 
        const selectedNode = this.nzTreeService.getSelectedNode();
        if (selectedNode && selectedNode.key !== node.key && !node.isExpanded && !node.isLeaf) {
          node.setExpanded(true);
          this.renderTree();
        }
      */
      this.nzOnDragEnter.emit(event);
      break;
    case 'dragover':
      this.nzOnDragOver.emit(event);
      break;
    case 'dragleave':
      this.nzOnDragLeave.emit(event);
      break;
    case 'dragend':
      this.nzOnDragEnd.emit(event);
      break;
    case 'drop':
      this.renderTree();
      this.nzOnDrop.emit(event);
      break;
  }
}
```